# how to get all events available in fullcalendar in react

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

am integrating react with fullcalender ( my case i have to drop some external components into a calendar ). went through their documentation and followed their steps Finally, I can able to drop external components into react fullcalendar. But I don't know how to get all the events in Callender using React. can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

[code sandbox of my repo](https://codesandbox.io/s/7zw04w3vn0?fontsize=14)

Here am initializing the data from the state, if I drag the event to another date. then how get updated events which are present on fullcaldendar using react

Answer (score 0):

They recently posted a [port to React](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-react) (and Vue, and Angular), so you can put in your events using your framework. I am currently integrating the Angular version, seems pretty easy. It's still in beta though...